# SQL Current Weeks Saturday Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to complete my WHERE clause with all the activity happened since start of Saturday  i.e. midnight.

e.g.

> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Time > ***Where Saturday Starts in Current
>   Week***

Comment: How do you like to define your weeks? There are many different ways that weeks are defined depending on where you live and what your culture is. Is Saturday the first day in a week?

Comment: @MarkByers I'm not sure about it. I'm in UK and believe Sunday is first day of the week. It there a way by which I can mention 'Saturday

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE Time > (SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()-5) DAY))
```

Explanation:

`WEEKDAY(CURDATE()-5)` will give you the index of the weekday for the current day. Since Saturday has the index `5` you need to subtract that. If you want last Sunday for example you would substract `6`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

Comment: I wonder can you please explain CURDATE() - 5. If Current Date is 28th July and -5 is 23rd July. Weekday will give me index of that day?